# Remove extra padding under a list item, Justify it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was wondering if this is at all possible. There is extra indentation under an ordered list I have set up and I want to remove it. I want it to look like this:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

Like I want it to be completely justified. I am using bootstrap but I couldn't find anything in their docs. Is what I am trying to do at all possible?

My HTML isn't really special. To get the first result it is just a p tag

```
 <div class="text-justify">
  <p class="grey-text"> 1. Applicable rules...<br><br>2. Definitions..</p>
 </div>
```

For the second result I just have

```
  <ol>
   <li> Applicable rules...</li>
   <li> Definitions...</li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: Can you insert your html and css so we can help you better?

Comment: I added the html. I am using bootstrap. The css isn't anything special neither was the html. I am just looking for a general way to do what I showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list-style-position: inside`:

```
ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/px7k48gs/) to see if this is what you desire.